# Integration: Question regarding adding a constant to the limits

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

I have to show that if $f$ is continuous in the interval $[a,b]$ were $λ≠0$ is a constant, then we have the following statements, that I need to prove are correct:

$$\tag{a} \int_a^b f(x) \, \Bbb dx = \int_{a+\lambda}^{b+\lambda} f(x-\lambda) \, \Bbb dx$$

$$\tag{b} \int_a^b f(x) \, \Bbb dx = \frac 1 \lambda \int_{\lambda a}^{\lambda b} f \left( \frac x \lambda \right) \, \Bbb dx.$$

The question gives a hint that I need to use integration by substitution.

I’m lost. Please help.

Comment: Make  an edit and show what you've tried. Please avoid no clue questions and take a [tour](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Poorly written question will attract downvotes. After showing us some effort someone surely come to help! Btw do you know in the first stance what integration by substitutions means?

Comment: Did you know that $\int_{a}^{b}{f[g(x)]g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x} = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}{f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u}$?